# Problem loading all of the resources for a single page application from REST API using Node.js and Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, rest, single-page-application

I'm trying to run this Single Page Application in node.js + express.js but I can only load the html file and not the required 2 JavaScript files.
[image: Project Structure]

weather.js

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const controller = require("./controller");
const path = require("path");

const router = new Router();

router.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public", "home.html"));
});

router.post(
  "/district/",
  [controller.auther, controller.admin],
  controller.addDistrict
);
router.post(
  "/data/",
  [controller.auther, controller.editor],
  controller.addData
);
router.get("/", [controller.auther, controller.viewer], controller.getData);
router.post("/auth", controller.auth);

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const weatherRoutes = require("./src/weather");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/api/weather", weatherRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`));
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="countrymap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mapdata.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Error]

Tried change the file locations of the js files.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [base tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) to `home.html`

```
  <base href="/" target="_blank">
```

> The **`<base>`** [HTML](/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) element specifies the base URL to
> use for all *relative* URLs in a document. There can be only
> one `<base>` element in a document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <base href="/" target="_blank">
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="countrymap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mapdata.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work, I'm thinking it's something I missed in the server.js or weather.js.

Comment: it gives the same error..? your route is: `http://localhost:3000/api/weather/home`, what happens when you go to it

Comment: Yes, I get the same error as above (in console)

Comment: well, adding base href is the main problem, I think, so it should work now. . your routing is a bit confusing, especially if you moved files (I'm not sure is it in `src` or not..) so, try renaming home to `index.html`, and then when you visit `http://localhost:3000` it should serve it, and then see if it works, and if it does, then try renaming it back to home and see if it works on the home route

Comment: maybe also disable other router middleware, just to make sure the file is served for now and it's not interfering somehow

Answer (score 0):

- Moved public folder out of src
- Removed all code relevant to hosting a SPA
- Added this code to server.js `app.use(express.static("public"));`
- Changed home.html to index.html
- Works at http://localhost:3000/